# Get active camera from VSE Scene strip (Animation Nodes)

Tags: camera, animation-nodes

I have same scene overlayed many times in **VSE** with different cameras. Is it possible to intercept *Camera* used for override during rendering from **VSE** *Scene* strip?

[image]

`Get Active Camera` node can only show default cameras used in actual scene, `Sequence Info` also doesn't have this option

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an expression to get the `scene_camera` attribute of the sequence strip.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Actualy this is a bit not what I am looking for. I assume that VSE strips render in order and I can get a camera which is being used at the moment. For example we have two strips sharing same scene exactly, for combo *Strip1+Camera1* nothing changes in the scene, but for *Strip2+Camera2* material's color turns green. If it is physically impossible than OK, I'll go with separate rendering, just need to be sure.

Comment: @SergeL Not sure how this works. Sorry.